# Deleting a guest profile in CDP

Tags: cdp

Has anyone tried deleting a guest profile in CDP when a request to forget comes from a customer?
The documentation seems a little confusing, about the process to create a batch first and then send request also the method of the request is not mentioned.
https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/using-guest-delete.html

Comment: this is the procedure to support the right to erasure: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-cdp/support-the-right-to-erasure.html

Comment: Recieved this info from slack - use  interactive APIs, just by making a "DELETE" verb request to https://api.boxever.com/v2/guests/{GUESTREF} it should return a 200 Success.  You should verify that this is working correctly.  It may take up to 24 hours for the Guest to be removed.  Also authentication is the same as other Interactive APIs using Basic Auth with username/password being the client key/access token.

Answer (score 4):

Now we have the refreshed documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/api/index-en.html#UUID-8670c6de-1ff7-1682-71a4-abe1bf20da49).

You have to use the **Guest Delete** endpoint in the Sitecore CDP Batch API to delete a guest record and all associated entities such as orders, sessions and events.

**Please note, that once a guest record is deleted you cannot restore it back!**

The below is a quick overview of how to delete a Guest:

1. Upload a batch file containing the concerned guest records. Ensure
   that every guest record is aligned with the guest delete data model
   and has all mandatory fields specified: `ref`, `schema`, `mode`,
   `value`. A classic example in case you use the email attribute as an identifier will be as follows:

```
{      
    "ref":"e6f467b1-4d45-4cbf-9709-329f3e202951",   
    "schema":"guest",
    "mode":"delete",
    "value":{  
          "email":"john.doe@gmail.com"
    }
 }
```

Note, that there are two options for the `mode` attribute: `gdpr_delete` and `delete`. So, if you are deleting the guest records in order to meet the GDPR compliance, use the `gdpr_delete` mode, otherwise use the `delete` mode for any other reason.

2. If there is enough identifying information then the Guest Delete endpoint will attempt to find a guest record and permanently delete
   it.

   In case the Guest Delete endpoint finds more than one guest with    matching identities it will delete the first one and return
   a 200    Response like `n matches found for this guest, 1st match deleted`,    and you will need to perform the same procedure to
   delete the    remaining records.

   If no matching guests were found then the Guest Delete endpoint will
   return a 404 Response like `Guest not found`.